# Layout iPhone and iPad xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, autolayout

I've question, I need create a new layout just only portrait for iPhone and iPad, so I am confuse which choose is correctly for it?

wRegular x hAny or wRegular x hCompact?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: According to this site (http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift) you will need two size classes. iPhone portrait: `wCompact hRegular` and iPad portrait: `wRegular hAny`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you drag out the size blue square you get a helpful explanation for each of the sizes. For example:

[image]